# Gitlab with specfic runner at DigitalOcean return error during connect dial tcp: lookup docker on 67.207.67.3:53: no such host

Tags: python, docker, gitlab, digital-ocean, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to implement CD for my dockerized Django app using Gitlab with a specific runner at a DigitalOcean droplet.

Here's my **`.gitlab-ci.yml`**

```
image:
  name: docker/compose:1.29.2
  entrypoint: [""]

services:
  - docker:dind
  # - docker:18-dind

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

before_script:
  - export IMAGE=$CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE/$CI_PROJECT_NAME
  - export WEB_IMAGE=$IMAGE/web:web
  - export NGINX_IMAGE=$IMAGE/nginx:nginx
  - apk add --no-cache openssh-client bash
  - chmod +x ./setup_env.sh
  - bash ./setup_env.sh
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/py_key
  - cat ~/.ssh/py_key
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/py_key
  - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
  - ssh-add ~/.ssh/py_key
  - ssh-keyscan -H 'gitlab.com' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - pythonist
  script:
    - docker pull $IMAGE/web:web || true
    - docker pull $IMAGE/nginx:nginx || true
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.ci.yml build
    - docker push $IMAGE/web:web
    - docker push $IMAGE/nginx:nginx

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - chmod +x ./deploy.sh
    - scp  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r ./.env ./docker-compose.prod.yml root@$DO_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:/root/Pythonist.org/
    - bash ./deploy.sh
  only:
    - master
```

And here's the **`gitlab-runner/config.toml`:**

```
[[runners]]
  name = "pythonist-on-gitlab"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/ci"
  token = "token"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker/compose:1.29.2"
    privileged = flase
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    # volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    #privileged = true
    volumes = ["/cache","/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
```

When I push to the repository to trigger a build, here's the error I get:

> $ docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY

> WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use
> --password-stdin.

> error during connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.40/auth: dial tcp: lookup docker on
> 67.207.67.3:53: no such host

What might be wrong here?

Comment: It looks like it's trying to connect to `docker` but that doesn't appear to be a valid host/domain name. Should that be `hub.docker.com` or is it supposed to connect to a running container called `'docker'`?